# Как установить цвет фона не у всего JComboBox, а только у его текстового поля?

Tags: java, swing

Нужно реализовать выбор цвета, использую JComboBox. Написал такой рендерер:

```
private class ColorCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {
        protected DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JLabel renderer = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
                isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value instanceof Color) {
                renderer.setBackground((Color) value);
                renderer.setText(" ");
            } 
            return renderer;
        }
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при выборе элемента из списка JComboBox, фоновый цвет меняется у всего JComboBox (включая кнопку), а не только у его тектового поля.

Comment: если вы уже перепробовали все сеттеры и ничего не вышло то можно проверить есть ли вообще возможность его изменить: поменяйте look & feel. если цвет меняется: поменять настройки look & feel / написать свой  
в любом случае: пронаследоватся от JComboBox и перегрузить метод который рисует компоненту

Comment: большое спасибо, решил попробовать написать свой look & feel.

Comment: нашел интересную ссылку: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4337049

Comment: Нашел способ не использовать LaF. Нужно написать свой эдитор и прикрутить такой ActionListener:

    jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         jComboBox.getComponents()[0].setBackground(new JComboBox().getBackground());
            }
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

и еще одно более изящное решение, в котором достаточно дописать в рендерер одну строчку кода и забыть о написании своего эдитора:

list.setSelectionBackground((Color) value);